# Can assumptions of a statistical test be tested post-hoc?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, levenes-test

Suppose I ran 100 1-factor ANOVAs. I find some significant results. Now, since ANOVA has some assumptions, I should test if they hold. So, can I run for example Levene's tests (to check equity of variances) post-hoc?

Comment: Why did you run 100 ANOVAs? Not for finding if *any* of the variables give significant effect, aren't you..? However if you did see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem

Comment: Keep in mind (as Tim mentions in comment above) that, even if the mean is same across all the groups in every one of 100 ANOVAs, you should still expect 5 of them to come out significant at the 0.05 level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [statistical inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_inference) consists of several parts, and besides estimation and hypothesis tests you should also look at goodness-of-fit and and whether the model assumptions are being met. If the fit is poor or assumptions are being violated you should consider other models, and treat the results that you have with caution. If your model assumes homogeneity of variances (homoscedasticity), it is a good idea to check if the assumption holds.

Depending on exactly what you've done, you should also consider that running 100 1-factor ANOVAs might lead to the [problems of multiple testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem).